# Errors when importing from MariaDB to MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

My server `A`use MariaDB 10.0 (InnoDB), and serer `B` use MySQL 5.5. They both run Linux.

I want to import all of `A`s databases into `B`.

At server `A`, I use `mysqldump` to export all databases,and to generate SQL file:

```
mysqldump -u user -p pwd --all-databases > all.sql
```

At server `B`, I use `source` to import:

```
source /home/all.sql
```

The problem is the implementation of an error source;
[image]

Comment: I don't know the source of this exact problem but `mysqldump` takes a number of output formatting options, those might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

Use the target's mysqldump to dump the source data.  That is, use MySQL 5.5's `mysqldump` to extract the data from MariaDB 10.  This procedure should minimize the differences encountered.

If that fails, prepare to edit the dump file.

5.5 is EOL, why move to such an old version?